# Центрирование элемента по вертикали

Tags: html, css

Как можно отцентрировать элемент по вертикали, если этот элемент постоянно изменяется в размерах? 
Как это сделать без table?

P.S. Имеется ввиду отцентировать по центру родительского элемента.

P.S.S. И что означает стиль margin: auto auto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

margin: auto auto - центрирование по горизонтали. Сокращенная запись

```
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
/*Это первое слово auto*/

/*центрирование по горизонтали*/
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
/*это второе слово auto*/
/*центрирование по горизонтали заккончено*/
```

Самый верный способ - таки использовать таблицы, но при блочной верстке:

```
div.parent{
  display: table-cell;
}
```

+использовать свойство vertical-align.

Есть еще вариант -

```
top: 50%; 
margin-top: -THISHEIGHT
```

, но тогда придется отслеживать высоту элемнта.

Comment: понимает ли IE7 display: table-cell ?

Comment: Седьмой - да.
Пруфлинк:
http://www.student.oulu.fi/~laurirai/www/css/middle/